# Sinatra EC2 Deployment Security Group Error

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, sinatra

I am trying to deploy a Ruby Sinatra api onto port 4567 of an EC2 micro instance.

I have created a Security Group with the following rules (and created the instance with said security group):

```
--------------------------------
| Ports | Protocol | Source    |
--------------------------------
|  22   | tcp      | 0.0.0.0/0 |
|  80   | tcp      | 0.0.0.0/0 |
|  443  | tcp      | 0.0.0.0/0 |
|  4567 | tcp      | 0.0.0.0/0 |
--------------------------------
```

I bound myapp.rb on port 4567 (the default, but for verbosity):

```
set :port, 4567
```

and ran the service:

```
ruby myapp.rb
[2013-09-05 03:12:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-09-05 03:12:54] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-01-15) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra/1.4.3 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2013-09-05 03:12:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1811 port=4567
```

Used `nmap` while ssh'd in the EC2 instance on localhost:

```
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-09-05 03:13 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00019s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
4567/tcp open  tram

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds
```

Used `nmap` while ssh'd in the EC2 instance on the external ip:

```
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-09-05 03:15 UTC
Nmap scan report for <removed>
Host is up (0.0036s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
4567/tcp closed tram

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.11 seconds
```

How do I change the state of the port from closed to open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re starting Sinatra in the development environment. When running in development [Sinatra only listens to requests from the local machine](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__server_hostname_or_ip_address).

There a few ways to change this, the simplest is probably to run in the [production environment](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Environments), e.g.:

```
$ ruby myapp.rb -e production
```

You could also explicitly set the bind variable if you wanted to keep running in development:

```ruby
set :bind, '0.0.0.0' # to listen on all interfaces
```

Comment: Awesome. the `-e production` flag didn't work in my case but the `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` opened access to the port 4567. Thank you!

Comment: @user1296908 Are you using [modular style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps)? It doesn’t look like the command line flags work for modular style apps, only classic style. You can set the `RACK_ENV` env variable from the command line if you want, modular apps will respect the setting then.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible causes for your problem.

1. Your service is only listening to connections on the loopback interface.
2. A software firewall is running and is blocking connections from outside on that port.

Comment: Yes I came to the same conclusion too. I just didn't know how to fix it. Thank you.